# Laravel more time using token

Tags: forms, laravel, token

I would like to know how can I remove token in form POST method because when I need between 10 and 15 min to fill a form and when I send it, I receive a token exception  and I lost all my data.

Thank's for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend removing the token. Instead increase the expiry time or after post redirect back with input values.

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
         return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('token', csrf_token());
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```